# Can't read file when NSProgress shows complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use `[manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response){}]` to download something.

I read downloaded file when **progress.fractionCompleted==1** by using KVO. And I find that something I get a **nil** when I read the file.

So, I want to know **when** I can read file. And **progress complete** means **completely write file on disk** or just **receive all the data**.

**EDIT**

```
- (void)URLSession:(__unused NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(__unused NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(__unused int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    self.progress.totalUnitCount = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    self.progress.completedUnitCount = totalBytesWritten;
}
```

So, it should be writing file first then setting progress? But why I get a nil???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to track progress in your delegate method if you want to display some sort of progress to the user. But that is *not* how you know when to grab the file.

The way to know when you can grab the file is when the delegate method `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` fires. You must grab the file *in that delegate method*.

And you must do it *immediately*. You cannot use KVO in between, because in the interval between the moment the delegate method fires and the moment you are notified via KVO, the file may be destroyed. It is destroyed *when we return* from `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:`. That is why you must grab it *inside* that method, and nowhere else.